# Difficulty turning a quadratic equation to "vertex"-form

Tags: quadratics

I'm having difficulty reducing a quadratic equation to its "vertex-form" by following my textbook and nearly every tutorial I can find online.

The starting equation is:

$$f(x) = -2x^2 + 16x - 24$$

Next, I divided each term by $-2$ (to leave the first term as $x^2$):

$$ = x^2 - 8x + 12$$

Next, to complete the square, I divide $x$'s coefficient by $2$, then square it ($(b/2)^2$):

$$\left(\frac{8}{2}\right)^2 = 16$$

Which gives me $16$. I add $16$ to complete the square, but also subtract it so it doesn't affect the value:

$$ = x^2 - 8x + 16 + 12 - 16$$

Finally, I complete the square:

$$ = (x - 4)^2 + 12 - 16$$

Then simplify:

$$= (x - 4)^2 - 4$$

According to by book though,the answer is:

$$-2(x - 4)^2 + 8$$

Unfortunately, the text skips over steps and makes it very unclear how they got the answer that they did. Can anyone point out where I went wrong above? I compiled the above steps from several videosand tutorials, but I must have gone wrong somewhere.

Comment: $$f(x) = -2x^2 + 16x - 24 = -2(x^2 - 8x) - 24 = -2(x^2 - 8x + 16) - 24 + 32 = -2(x - 4)^2 + 8$$

Comment: @Arnie Thank you. That's the same way the text did it. The guides I read though suggest that it's best to get rid of the first coefficient first, but neither you or the text did. Also, where did I go wrong above? If you gave a little more detail in the form of an answer, I would gladly accept it.

Comment: Hint - you don't "get rid of the first coefficient", you just *factor it out*.

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made your error when you divided by $-2$.  When you divided $f(x) = -2x^2 + 16x - 24$ by $-2$, you obtained $\color{red}{f(x) = x^2 - 8x + 12}$.  The expression in red is not equal to the original function since the $y$-intercept of the original function is $-24$, while the $y$-intercept of the function in red is $12$.

You want to transform the equation $f(x) = -2x^2 + 16x - 24$ into the form $f(x) = a(x - h)^2 + k$.  We first extract a factor of $-2$ from the quadratic and linear terms so that the expression in parentheses has the form $x^2 + 2kx$.  We do this since we want to complete the square on $x^2 + kx$ to form the perfect square $x^2 + 2kx + k^2 = (x + k)^2$.
\begin{align*}
f(x) & = -2x^2 + 16x - 24\\
     & = -2(x^2 - 8x) - 24
\end{align*}
The term in parentheses now has the form $x^2 + 2kx$, where $2k = -8$, so $k = -4$, and $k^2 = 16$.  If we add $16$ inside the parentheses, we will obtain the perfect square $x^2 - 8x + 16 = (x - 4)^2$.  However, adding $16$ inside the parentheses adds $-2 \cdot 16 = -32$ to the original expression, we must add $32$ to the expression in order to balance the equation.
\begin{align*}
f(x) & = -2(x^2 - 8x) - 24\\
     & = -2(x^2 - 8x + 16) - 24 + 32\\
     & = -2(x - 4)^2 + 8
\end{align*}
which tells us that the graph of $f(x)$ has vertex $(4, 8)$ and opens downwards.  Note that the $y$-intercept is 
$$f(0) = -2(0 - 4)^2 + 8 = -2(16) + 8 = -32 + 8 = -24$$
as we would expect.

**Check:** We verify that the vertex form is equal to the original function. 
\begin{align*}
f(x) & = -2(x - 4)^2 + 8\\
     & = -2(x^2 - 8x + 16) + 8\\
     & = -2x^2 + 16x - 32 + 8\\
     & = -2x^2 + 16x - 24
\end{align*}
*Completing the square* refers to the process of adding $k^2$ to an expression of the form $x^2 + 2kx$ to form the perfect square $x^2 + 2kx + k^2$.  One purpose of completing the square is to transform a quadratic function into vertex form.  What confused you is that it can also be used to solve for the $x$-intercepts.  When we solve for the $x$-intercepts, we set $f(x) = 0$ and solve for $x$.  It is here that we divide by $-2$ (or, more generally, the leading coefficient).  Continuing from above yields
\begin{align*}
f(x) & = 0\\
-2(x - 4)^2 + 8 & = 0\\
(x - 4)^2 - 4 & = 0\\
(x - 4)^2 & = 4\\
x - 4 & = \pm 2\\
x & = 4 \pm 2
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
x & = 4 + 2 & x & = 4 - 2\\
x & = 6 & x & = 2
\end{align*}
You can verify that these solutions are correct by substituting them into the equation $f(x) = -2x^2 + 16x - 24$.

Comment: Thank you. Great explanation.

Comment: Wait, I'm confused by something. If you look in this guide, about half way down the page, it states "Step 1: Divide all terms by `a`", but that seems to contradict your first paragraph. https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/completing-square.html

Comment: Note that the goal on that page is to solve a quadratic equation rather than to place a quadratic function in vertex form.  If you want to solve a quadratic equation, as I did to find the $x$-intercepts of the function $f(x) = -2x^2 + 16x - 24$, then you divide by the leading coefficient (in this case, by $-2$).